# unpacking Download.img firmware for alcatel mw40

Tags: firmware, unpacking

Hello i'm trying to unpack file Download.img from alcatel mw40 (based on qualcomm 9x07) firmware but it seems i can't do it with 7zip or mount the img file . someone already extracted the file which will give partition images like this :

```
appsboot_fastboot.mbn
appsboot.mbn
b.vhd
config.xml
custom_info.xml
efs.mbn
ENPRG9x07.mbn
jrdresource.ubi
mdm9607-boot.img
mdm9607-sysfs.ubi
NON-HLOS.ubi
NPRG9x07.mbn
partition.mbn
rpm.mbn
sbl1.mbn
tz.mbn
```

under linux the format of the file is :

```
file Download.img 
Download.img: dBase III DBT, version number 0, next free block index 65545, 1st item "D\343\006"
```

anyone can show how to unpack this file to get the list of mentioned files above
thanks for help , i'm trying to learn how.
file link  [Download.img](http://www.mediafire.com/file/abggflriq8ukmge/Download.img)

Comment: Can You help please?
I have same problem
I use command C:\Python27\python.exe code.py Download.img
but I get error:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "('Download.img.out/', u'NPRG9x07.mbn')wb" any one can suggest what I'm doing wrong? NPRG9x07.mbn it's one of the files but somehow is not extracting anything. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file format consists of a file table starting at 0xC8 with each entry being:

- char filename[48]
- uint32_t position
- uint32_t size

Where `position` indicates the position in the archive and `size` the archived file's size.

Run `code.py Download.img` to extract the files and place them into `Download.img.out/`:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import sys
import struct

if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
    print('usage: {} file'.format(sys.argv[0]))
    exit(1)

path = '{}.out/'.format(sys.argv[1])

if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.makedirs(path)

with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as f:
    i = 0
    while True:
        f.seek(0xC8 + i*0x50)
        name = f.read(0x48).decode('ascii').split('\x00')[0]
        if (len(name) == 0): break
        if struct.calcsize('II') == 0x08:
            v = struct.unpack('II', f.read(0x08))
        elif struct.calcsize('LL') == 0x08:
            v = struct.unpack('LL', f.read(0x08))
        else:
            print("Unsupported platform")
            exit(1)
        f.seek(v[0])
        out = open('{}{}'.format((path, name), 'wb'))
        out.write(f.read(v[1]))
        out.close()
        i += 1
    f.close()
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer , i'm getting this error : 
python code.py Download.img
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 20, in <module>
    v = struct.unpack('LL', f.read(0x08))
struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 16

Comment: also if i add a print(f) right after name = ... and after v = struct.unpack 
i get same value : the output of print(f) is same twice 
<open file 'Download.img', mode 'rb' at 0x7fda9c519780>
<open file 'Download.img', mode 'rb' at 0x7fda9c519780>

Comment: Thanks actually i tried the script on a windows machine with python version 2.7 and this script actually worked as expected , i don't know why it did not work on linux ubuntu machine , maybe the python version is not compatible i'll look for it later . thanks

Comment: Doesn't work because of parenthesis in the out=open. Here is the good one : `out = open('{}{}'.format(path, name), 'wb')`

Comment: Does this also works for Alcatel MW40V?

Comment: Now that is unpacked, how can I upgrade?