# How can I flash unpacked firmware into Alcatel MiFi?

Tags: firmware, binary, flash, rom

I bought Alcatel MW40V from Vodafone Shop some weeks ago and I can't access USSD Codes within Web UI.

```
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 1bbb:0195 T & A Mobile Phones Alcatel OneTouch L850V / Telekom Speedstick LTE

Software Version:   MW40_00_02.00_25
Device Name:    MW40
IMEI:   352491109846647
MAC Address:    f0:51:36:3d:2e:18
IP Address:     192.168.1.1
Subnet Mask:    255.255.255.0
```

I'm facing annoying issues with preinstalled firmware and somehow I can't update normally and I know there were supposed to be updates pending.

Recently I unpacked firmware from [IMG](https://androidhost.ru/SHf?pt=UVROdlF6TTJhMVp3WnpJemNrdGFkWGRTTTBFd2R6MDlPdGx2Y0xZbTlSa0RQZzI0bGhlM1diVT0%3D) file with help of another [post](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/21776/unpacking-download-img-firmware-for-alcatel-mw40), but now I'm stuck and don't know what to do afterwards.

I tried to flash it with Alcatel [TPST TPW](https://androidhost.ru/SVp) like on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d0UeA3gsc1c) video, but didn't work (Maybe because of ID mismatch).

Please help!